# Java Swing: JProgressBar for resource loading

Tags: java, swing

I am making a mini "os" for my USB drive and I am working on the Booter right now. I have a label that says Loading... and a JProgressBar now I want to program it to setValue() everytime a resource loads etc... other classes.. images... etc how do I do that so far I have this

**Main.java**

```
package mini.operating.sys;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        mini.operating.sys.ConfigureClasses.configureBooter();
    }
}
```

**Booter.java**

```
package mini.operating.sys;

public class Booter extends javax.swing.JWindow
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Booter()
    {
        setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());
        javax.swing.JLabel l = new javax.swing.JLabel("Loading...");
        javax.swing.JProgressBar p = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
        l.setToolTipText("Loading resources...");
        p.setValue(0);
        p.setStringPainted(true);
        add(l);
        add(p);
    }
}
```

**And finally ConfigureClasses.java**

```
package mini.operating.sys;

public class ConfigureClasses 
{
    public static void configureBooter()
    {
        Booter b = new Booter();
        b.setSize(300, 60);
        b.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        b.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I want to setValue of the JProgressBar towards 100 after all files load starting with what I have now how do I do this?

Comment: @Palle...pretty good but you only need one s.in resource thank you for editing the question though.. whatever gets it answered.

Comment: Obviously you need to know how many resources you're going to load  and the ID use a SwingWorker, which has progress support and can be used to update the progress bar

Comment: So how is that done? Right now the only resources I need to load are my classes.

Comment: [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)